# C# - Combobox Items contain spaces after importing from dataset

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering if someone could tell me why when I populate my combobox from a dataset with several columns, there are spaces(about 5 spaces) in each row between the column values.

code

```
thisConnect.Open();

SqlDataAdapter sqladapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT firstname, lastname, address FROM OwnersTbl", thisConnect);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

sqladapt.Fill(ds, "OwnersTbl");

thisConnect.Close();

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
  comboBoxOwners.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + "" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] + "" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2]);
}
```

Comment: Because you're using char instead of varchar data type in the database perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment.  If it is char(30) then you will get 30 characters.
Try

```
select rtrim(firstname) ...
```

OR

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].Trim()
```

And it is not always better to go varchar.
If the values are initially empty and you add then can cause page splits.
But a char(30) will hold that space.

Comment: Thanks guys, as soon as I trimmed the data, it eliminated the spaces.

Comment: If that is and answer then check it?